# Why CGSize doesn't use * when declaring variables?

Tags: objective-c

When I create an instance of a class called, say, Sprite, I do something like:

```
Sprite *mySprite = [[Sprite alloc]init];
```

But why when creating a CGSize or int type variable, I can't use *? Basically, what's the * for?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The * denotes a [pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29). `CGSize` is declared as a `struct` and `Sprite` is a class, and in Objective-C all classes are referenced by a pointer.

---

*You can find additional information in the [Programming with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html) documentation. The relevant sections are **Use Pointers to Keep Track of Objects** and **Methods Can Return Values***.

Comment: to add to Joe's correct answer, an `int` is a primitive type, and is stored directly in memory and therefore not referenced by pointer generally.

Comment: FWIW, "Everything you need to know about pointers in C" (http://boredzo.org/pointers/) is applicable to Objective C too.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis Thanks I was looking for some good articles to add to the post, the OP needs to read up on the basics of pointers.

Comment: I personally like my own article on pointers better **;-)**, but that is for Delphi users and uses Delphi syntax, not Obj-C.