# What's the difference between (ReturnClass *)methodName... and (ReturnClass)methodName... in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

Quick question: The difference between `(ReturnClass *)methodName...` and `(ReturnClass)methodName`... in Objective-C?

I know (ReturnType *)methodName... returns an **instance** of ReturnClass as opposed to `(ReturnClass)methodName` *just returning what?*

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why CGSize doesn't use \* when declaring variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071616/why-cgsize-doesnt-use-when-declaring-variables)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your `ReturnClass` is an object (which is most likely) then you can't use it without *. You'll get a compilation error. Otherwise *is a pointer to instance (primitive type or struct), and absence of * is instance itself

EDIT: Brilliant explanation on pointers from Joe:

> Think of the instance as your house and the pointer as your address. Your house is a large object, so instead of making copies of your house and passing it to your friends when you have a party you give them your address so they can get to your house. Now if you had a small object, like a flyer, it would be easy to just make copies and pass out rather than give everyone instructions to get to that piece of paper. Think of the large object (house) as an Objective-C class or struct full of info, and the small object (flyer) as a primitive like int, BOOL, double etc

Comment: It doesn't have to be a subclass of `NSObject`, if it is an Objective-C class it is required to be referenced by a pointer. It is possible to create other root classes, that is why there is an [`NSObject` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSObject). An example would be [`NSProxy`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSProxy_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Good answer! But now what is the difference between a pointer to an instance and the instance itself?! I don't get it, i've read this a couple of times, and they seem to me to be the same. The only differentiating factor would be if the said instance changed over time. In the first case a pointer to that instance would reflect the changes also while the instance itself, being passed before the changes were made, the receiver would have no clue about the changes and display the old instance?!

Comment: Think of the instance as your house and the pointer as your address. Your house is a large object, so instead of making copies of your house and passing it to your friends when you have a party you give them your address so they can get to your house. Now if you had a small object, like a flyer, it would be easy to just make copies and pass out rather than give everyone instructions to get to that piece of paper. Think of the large object (house) as an Objective-C class or struct full of info, and the small object (flyer) as a primitive like int, BOOL, double etc..

Comment: Simply - pointer is the ADDRESS of an instance. Despite the notion of pointers is very simple it usually takes a lot of time to grasp it completely.

Comment: @Joe brilliant explanation. I have nothing to add

Comment: Great, I have a better grasp now. However, what is the difference in use between the two? If a method is called and returns the address to the said object, then the object which called the method will go to that address and be able to interact with it. My understanding would be like this... on a GRAND perspective having millions of these objects they all pass around envelopes with addresses on them and not actual objects. Then at a LOWER perspective you would have, actual objects being passed aroung. The only thing I can "see" is that the objects referenced by addresses are somehow "longlived"

Comment: @Joe Great, I was thinking the same thing. So the actual difference is apparent like this... "bigger", more long-lived objects interact by passing around messages to and about each other, while the "smaller" objects are just copied and thrown around, since the information they hold is not useful in the long term and is only of interest in the short-term (lifecycle of the method, some mundane operation)

Comment: @AndreyChernukha Please edit your answer to include Joe's comments and I'll accept the answer. Thank you so much to both of you.