# How to count number of dictionaries within a dictionary obj c?

Tags: objective-c, dictionary

I've tried:

```
NSUInteger *length = [dictionary count];
```

but this throws a "incompatible integer to pointer conversion" warning.

Basically my dictionary is as such:

```
{
     'thing1' {
            'item1' : 'item1value'
               }

     'thing2' {
            'item2: 'item2value'
               }
 }
```

Etc. you get the point.

What I'd like to know is how many "things" are in the dictionary, not how many items or item values..

Comment: `NSUInteger length = [dictionary count];` See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071616/why-cgsize-doesnt-use-when-declaring-variables/7071637#7071637) why some types require pointers `*` and some don't.

Comment: apologies, i hadn't noticed the missing pointer and thought joe's response was sarcastic

Comment: Please update your question with valid example code.

Comment: It should be noted that if you don't clearly understand the difference between pointers and simple values then you're pretty much doomed insofar as programming in Objective-C is concerned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSUInteger` is a basic integer type, not an object, `[dictionary count]` returns an `NSUInteger`, not a pointer to one (`NSUInteger *`) that's where the incompatible integer to pointer conversion warning comes from.

Just remove the `*`.

```
NSUInteger length = [dictionary count];
```

Comment: While that does address an error it does not address the somewhat cryptic question: "how many "things" are in the dictionary, not how many items or item values."

Comment: It's kind of cryptic, but easy to understand with his data example.

`things`: keys in the main dictionary. `items`: keys in the sub dictionaries. `item values`: values in the sub dictionaries.

So, he's asking how to count the amount of keys, and he's worried that it might do a deep search and count any object contained in the dictionary and sub dictionaries. The actual answer should be `[[dictionary allKeys] count]`, but that's because he didn't ask the right question. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you want to count then number of objects in a series of nested dictionaries and/or arrays.

```
@implementation NSDictionary (RecursiveCount)
- (NSUInteger)recursiveCount {
    return self.allValues.recursiveCount;
}
@end

@implementation NSArray (RecursiveCount)
- (NSUInteger)recursiveCount {
    int count = 0;
    for (id object in self) {
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] || [object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            count += [object recursiveCount];
        } else {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
@end
```

---

```
- (void)testRecursiveCount {
    NSDictionary *dict = @{
                           @"key1" : @[@1, @2, @3],
                           @"key2" : @{@"blah" : @[@[], @1, @[@1, @2]]},
                           @"key3" : @4,
                           @"key5" : @[@{@"blah":@[@{@1:@1}]}],
                           };
    XCTAssertEqual(dict.recursiveCount, 8, @"dictionary");

    NSArray *array = @[
                       @[@1, @2, @3],
                       @{@"blah" : @[@[], @1, @[@1, @2]]},
                       @4,
                       @[@{@"blah":@[@{@1:@1}]}],
                       ];
    XCTAssertEqual(array.recursiveCount, 8, @"array");
}
```

---

If all you want is a shallow count, the solution is trivial.

`dictionary.count;`

Comment: He actually wanted the shallow count. Quote: `What I'd like to know is how many "things" are in the dictionary, not how many items or item values..`.

Comment: @NiñoScript Which _could_ be interpreted as a recursive search.

Comment: Not if you read the poorly written example, in which "things" are the keys of the main dictionary and not the values (items) nor anything inside those values (item values)

Comment: @NiñoScript _Exactly_, it's a **poorly written question**. Which means that it can be interpreted many ways.